# How to save PGM bytes to a file

Tags: objective-c, pgm

We are taking a UIImage and converting it to PGM as an 8-bit grayscale representation of the image.

The result is an unsigned char array of the bytes. I want to write this to a file to check what it has converted. When I do that using:

```
NSData *rawPGM = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)somethingPGM length:strlen((char *)somethingPGM)];
NSURL *someurl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"temp.pgm"]];
[rawPGM writeToURL:someurl atomically:YES];
```

I get UTF-8 characters in the file, like `ÚÛÜÝÝÜÛÚ××ÖÙØÚÛ` instead of a set of integers 0-255 like a normal PGM file:

```
0 
24 
57 
76 
91 
103
```

How do I save the unsigned char * to a file containing the integer representations of those bytes?

Comment: Please post the code that's not working the way you expect.

Comment: thanks Andrew, edited to show the code writing to the file, which I know is not correct.